# SFDC - Query all contacts shared with a given user?

Tags: api, salesforce

I'm somewhat of a SFDC novice when it comes to integration, but is there any way I can query just the contacts shared with a given user, taking into account all the ways the share can occur? Essentially just see the same contacts the user would see in within the platform?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. I added some inline comments to explain what each step is doing. The end result should be all the contacts that can be read by a specified user in your org.

```
// add a set with all the contact ids in your org
List<contact> contacts = new List<contact>([Select id from Contact]);
Set<ID> contactids = new Set<ID>();
for(Contact c : contacts)
    contactids.add(c.id);

// using the user record access you can query all the recordsids and the level of access for a specified user
List<UserRecordAccess> ura = new List<UserRecordAccess>([SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel
     FROM UserRecordAccess
     WHERE UserId = 'theuserid'
     AND RecordId in: contactids
      ] );   

// unfortunatelly you cannot agregate your query on hasReadAccess=true so you'd need to add this step
Set<id> readaccessID = new Set<ID>();
for(UserRecordAccess ur : ura)
{
    if(ur.HasReadAccess==true)
    {
        readaccessID.add(ur.RecordID);
    }
}

// This is the list of all the Contacts that can be read by the specified user
List<Contact> readAccessContact = new List<Contact>([Select id, name from contact where id in: readaccessID]);

// show the results
system.debug( readAccessContact);
```